# Does react-script not support Typescript anymore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, create-react-app

I have a 2-year-old project that I made using CRA, and I am trying to migrate to using Typescript. This is now my package.json looks like:

```
@testing-library/jest-dom": "^(5.16.4",) 
"@testing-library/react": "^(13.3.0",) 
"@testing-library/user-event": "^(13.5.0",) 
"@types/jest": "^(29.5.3",) 
"@types/node": "^(20.5.0",) 
"@types/react": "^(18.2.20",) 
"@types/react-dom": "^(18.2.7",) 
...
"react": "^(18.2.0",) 
"react-dom": "^(18.2.0",) 
...
"typescript": "^(5.1.6",) 
"web-vitals": "^(2.1.4")
```

Now, I tried to compile my CRA using AWS Codebuild:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm ci
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build
      
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'build'
```

However, I am getting the error (summary: react-script: 5.0.1 does not support the latest typescript version and recommends downloading 3.x or 4.x typescript):

```
\[Container\] 2023/08/16 18:34:54 Running command npm ci 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE 
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1 
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.1.6 25npm ERR! node\_modules/typescript 
npm ERR!   typescript@"\^5.1.6" from the root project 
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2 28npm ERR!   node\_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin 
npm ERR!     fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"\^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.1 
npm ERR!     node\_modules/react-dev-utils 31npm ERR!       react-dev-utils@"\^12.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1 
npm ERR!       node\_modules/react-scripts 33npm ERR!         react-scripts@"\^5.0.1" from the root project 
npm ERR!   1 more (tsutils) 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: 
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"\^3.2.1 || \^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1 
npm ERR! node\_modules/react-scripts 39npm ERR!   react-scripts@"\^5.0.1" from the root project 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5 
npm ERR! node\_modules/typescript 
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"\^3.2.1 || \^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1 
npm ERR!   node\_modules/react-scripts 
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"\^5.0.1" from the root project 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry 
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps 
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! For a full report see: 
npm ERR! /root/.npm/\_logs/2023-08-16T18\_35\_12\_328Z-eresolve-report.txt 54 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/\_logs/2023-08-16T18\_35\_12\_328Z-debug-0.log 57 58\
```

Thus, this gets me wondering, does react-script not support typescript anymore?
I want to use typescript in my react project (CRA), what should I do?